# kcat protobuf deserialization

Tags: apache-kafka, protocol-buffers, kcat

I'm using kcat to check the content of kafka topics when working locally but, when messages are serialized with protobuf, the result I get is an unreadable stream of encoded characters. I'm aware of the existence of some other kafka-consumers tools ([Kafdrop](https://github.com/obsidiandynamics/kafdrop), [AKHQ](https://github.com/tchiotludo/akhq), [Kowl](https://github.com/cloudhut/kowl), [Kadek](https://www.kadeck.com/)...) but I'm looking for the simplest option which fits my needs.

**Does kcat support protobuf key/value deserialization from protofile?**
Is there any simple terminal-based tool which allows this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had luck with this command:

```
kcat -C -t <topic> -b <kafkahost>:9092 -o -1 -e -q -D "" | protoc --decode=<full message class> path/to/my.proto --proto_path <proto_parent_folder>
```

Update 12/2023 - Here's a more streamlined command with better guidance.

```
kcat -C -t <topic> -b <kafkahost>:9092 -o -1 -e -q -D "" | protoc --decode <package>.<Message Type> path/to/my.proto
```

Where  is the `package` defined in the `.proto` file and `<Message Type>` is the name of the Message.

Ie.:
`user.proto`:

```
package some.package;

message User {
  string id = 1;
  string email = 2;
}
```

The command would be:

```
kcat -C -t <topic_name> -b host.docker.internal:9092 -o -1 -e -q -D "" | protoc --decode some.package.User user.proto
```

Comment: And, following your sample command, if `my.proto` has dependencies with other protofiles these dependencies would be resolved as long as they are under `<proto_parent_folder>` right?

Comment: @frblazquez I believe so

Comment: Just want to mention that `<full message class>` means the full path of the class including "package".

Comment: "Missing input file." :(

Answer (score 1):

> any simple terminal-based tool which allows this

Only ones that integrate with the Confluent Schema Registry (which is what those linked tools use as well), e.g. `kafka-protobuf-console-consumer` is already part of Confluent Platform.

Regarding `kcat` - refer https://github.com/edenhill/kcat/issues/72 and linked issues

Answer (score 0):

> any simple terminal-based tool which allows this

I created [milena](https://github.com/VanceLongwill/milena) for exactly this use case. It's a small CLI for working with protobuf Kafka messages that decodes protobuf to json for ease of use with other tools such as `jq`.

For example, the following command would consume protobuf `some.package.User` events and write them to stdout as line delimited json.

```bash
milena consume \
  -X bootstrap.servers=host.docker.internal:9092 \
  --topic my-topic \
  --file-descriptors descriptors.binpb \
  --message-name some.package.User \
  --offset=beginning
```